# Monitor cell value and copy it to another cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I would like to know how to monitor a cell value and make this value always updating on some other cell.

Until now i was using the = sign and then choosing the cell i want to monitor.

The problem is that the row/cell i'm monitoring is constantly updating due to another vba script, and when that happens i get `REF` error.

e.g.

On the `M8` cell (sheet1) i have this simple formula to monitor the value in the summary sheet on the `A3` cell:

`=summary!A3` (works fine displaying the cell value)

But after the rows are deleted OR updated..i get this behaviour on the `M8` cell in the sheet1.

`=summary!#REF!`

Does anyone know how can i lock the formula so it never changes?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `=INDIRECT("summary!A3")` - this will ALWAYS refer to A3 regardless of any Sheet changes.

Comment: Peter, just one more question.

Im using that formula =INDIRECT("summary!A6") but this retrieves 0 when the cells are empty.

How can i make this not to display the real value of the cell? Using IFERROR maybe ?

Thanks

Comment: `=IF(INDIRECT("summary!A6")="","",INDIRECT("summary!A6"))`